# is it possible to pass data from one component to another using service without click event and it's method?

Tags: angular, typescript, service, components

want one component to get data from another when page is loaded

```
<app-header></app-header>
<button (click)="sendProductData()">send data</button>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: why are you against using a service? This would be textbook usecase of service :) ...unless we are talking about parent-child interaction (not router-outlet).

Comment: i,m using service but i created button. data passes to service and other component subscribes it when i press this button. i want service to get that data without pressing any buttons. when i reload page i want one component to get this data automatically

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, was an idiot and misread the title!

Comment: have you tried using BehaviorSubject ?

Comment: you might want to call "sendProductsData()" method inside ngOnInit(), isn't ?

Answer (score 0):

Two cases here:

1. your data is already loaded into your service when the two components are loaded. In that case simply put the subscripion in both compoenents in the `ngOnInit` hook and get the data.
2. Your data is only fetched when the button is clicked, in that case the subscription, as you do now, is loaded on click.

Think about data availibility during the app lifecycle and at which moment the components are entering the game!